# Should I forward the a call to .Equals onto .Equals<T>?

Tags: c#, programming-practices

So, I've got you bog standard c# object, overriding Equalsand implementing IEquatable

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Tag)
    }

    #region IEquatable<Tag> Members

    public bool Equals(Tag other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        else
            return _name == other._name;
    }

    #endregion
```

Now, for some reason, I used to think that forwarding the calls from Equals into Equals was bad, no idea why, perhaps I read it a long time ago, anyway I'd write separate (but logically same) code for each method.

Now I think forwarding Equals to Equals is okay, for obvious reasons, but for the life me I can't remember why I thought it wasn't before.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Should this be on StackOverflow?

Comment: No idea. I can't think of a situation where you'd want to duplicate your comparison logic. That's just asking for trouble. Choosing whether to have Equals(object) calling Equals(Tag) or the other way around seems like a stylistic choice to me.

Comment: @Anna: If `Equals(Tag)` calls `Equals(object)`, then you have the runtime type-check regardless of which method is called. If `Equals(object)` checks the type and calls `Equals(Tag)`, then you skip the check when the type is known.

Comment: @Anon.: Am I missing something? Sounds like there's a type check one way or another, regardless of who's doing it. Although I suppose you'd also incur a boxing cost if you go the Tag->object route, made worse by the fact that the Equals(object) implementation will probably unbox it, which is wasted effort if we know the type in the first place. So perhaps Equals(object)->Equals(Tag) is the better direction.

Comment: @Anna @ Anon Cheers Guys 
@FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Yea, I wasn't sure, I mean, as it focused more on practise than implemention, I thought it might be okay here.

Comment: @Anna: If I have two tags, and I call `a.Equals(b)`, there's no runtime typechecking going on (just the null test). Whereas if that gets forwarded to `a.Equals((object)b)`, then suddenly there's a typecheck necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is good practice but you have to be careful if `Tag` was a struct. If that is the case you want to do this.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is Tag && Equals((Tag)obj);
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a more efficient form ...

Comment: Wouldn't `obj as Tag` fail to compile if `Tag` was a struct?